# Can't run mvc 5 project locally in VS13 after system crash?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, project

As the title says I can't run my project in debugging mode locally in vs13 (MVC 5).

I was playing around with an overclock on my stationary comp, which turned out not to be stable (despire stress testing) and my pc bluescreened and rebooted while I was running the project (I've reverted back to a stable OC again). Now I get the same error everytime I run this particular project.

The weird thing is I tried uninstalling vs13 completely (with the force feature) and reinstalling it after a reboot and still this particular project will not run locally at all. The same project works fine on my coworkers comps and on my own laptop, but somehow it refuses to run on my stationary pc and apparently a reinstall hasn't fixed anything?

The error message you can see here [image: Error Message Screenshot]

Anyone got any clues or expert advice that could help me without me having to format my entire computer and reinstalling windows?

EDIT: Apparently you can't read the error lines properly so here is a snippet of most of it:

```
" Filen eller assemblyen 'Microsoft.Owin.Security' eller en af dens afhængigheder kunne ikke indlæses. Forkert parameter. (Undtagelse fra HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
Beskrivelse: Der opstod en undtagelse, der ikke blev behandlet, under udførelse af den aktuelle webanmodning. Se staksporingen for at få flere oplysninger om fejlen, og hvor den kom fra i koden.

Detaljer om undtagelse: System.IO.FileLoadException: Filen eller assemblyen 'Microsoft.Owin.Security' eller en af dens afhængigheder kunne ikke indlæses. Forkert parameter. (Undtagelse fra HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Kildefejl:

Der blev oprettet en undtagelse, der ikke blev behandlet,  under kørsel af den aktuelle webanmodning. Du kan finde oplysninger om undtagelsens oprindelse og placering ved hjælp af nedenstående staksporing af undtagelser.

Belastningssporing af assembly: Følgende oplysninger kan være nyttige, når det skal afgøres, hvorfor assemblyen 'Microsoft.Owin.Security' ikke kunne indlæses.


=== Tilstandsoplysninger om forudbinding ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Owin.Security
 (Partial)
WRN: Der blev leveret oplysninger om en delvis binding for en assembly:
WRN: Assemblynavn: Microsoft.Owin.Security | Domæne-id: 2
WRN: En delvis binding opstår, når der kun opgives en del af assemblyens viste navn.
WRN: Dette kan medføre, at binderen indlæser en forkert assembly.
WRN: Det anbefales at opgive fuldt specificeret tekst-id for assemblyen,
WRN: bestående af det simple navn, versionen, kulturen og token til offentlig nøgle.
WRN: Du kan få flere oplysninger om og almindelige løsninger til dette problem i hvidbogen http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Giuseppe/Desktop/ASP.NET/MEV3/MEV3/
LOG: Første PrivatePath = C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\ASP.NET\MEV3\MEV3\bin
Kalder assembly: (Unknown).
===
LOG: Denne binding starter i indlæsningskonteksten default.
LOG: Bruger programkonfigurationsfilen: C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\ASP.NET\MEV3\MEV3\web.config
LOG: Bruger værtskonfigurationsfilen: C:\Users\Giuseppe\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Bruger maskinkonfigurationsfil fra C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Politikken anvendes ikke på referencen på nuværende tidspunkt (privat, brugerdefineret, delvis eller placeringsbaseret assemblybinding).
LOG: Forsøger at hente nye URL-adresser file:///C:/Users/Giuseppe/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/6691a5d9/25f50715/Microsoft.Owin.Security.DLL.
LOG: Forsøger at hente nye URL-adresser file:///C:/Users/Giuseppe/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/6691a5d9/25f50715/Microsoft.Owin.Security/Microsoft.Owin.Security.DLL.
LOG: Forsøger at hente nye URL-adresser file:///C:/Users/Giuseppe/Desktop/ASP.NET/MEV3/MEV3/bin/Microsoft.Owin.Security.DLL.
LOG: Bruger programkonfigurationsfilen: C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\ASP.NET\MEV3\MEV3\web.config
LOG: Bruger værtskonfigurationsfilen: C:\Users\Giuseppe\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Bruger maskinkonfigurationsfil fra C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Postpolitikreference: Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
ERR: Konfigurationen af assemblyen mislykkedes (hr = 0x80070057). Testen afsluttedes.
"
```

Comment: It's just telling you that it can't load some OWIN related DLL. Try enabling nuget package restore and rebuilding (twice). If that fails, delete and reinstall your OWIN-related references with nuget.

Comment: If you set you thread culture to english at startup, you most probably get an English exception, which is more useful to us and Google.

Comment: I think spender is correct.  For some reason your system is not finding the DLL for owin.

Comment: I have both options enabled in the nuget package settings window (as per standard configuration) already, is there something I need to do additionally besides this part?

Comment: I tried reinstalling Owin through the package manager console "Install-Package Autofac.Mvc5.Owin" but it didn't solve the problem. :/

Comment: I mean "install-package microsoft.owin.security", still has not solved it.